# Creating a stopwatch in salesforce which calculates total time elapsed without using apex or visualforce

Tags: html, urlhacking

I had a request from client to create a stopwatch within Salesforce. I would like to share what I did, and see if anyone has better ideas.

Scenario: Client wishes to to create a stop watch which will allow them to start/stop the timer during a lengthy process of application process. Sometimes the time is actually wasted on Customer A's side, because the customer needs to gather documentation. Basically, the timer needs to be able to start and stop,  and then show the total elapsed time after multiple start-stops. At the end of the process, my client needs to be able to show that, despite the process taking 2 months from start to finish, the company only utilised 1 week to complete the process; the rest of the time was waiting for Customer A to take action on the other side.

This stop watch is to be visible at the Account object in Salesforce.

This is all to be done on Salesforce. I am not a coder by any measure. I am more admin-ish.....

Comment: What I had Done:

Basically, as I am not a coder, I had to use a non-coding method. After consulting with my senior colleagues, here is what we came up with.

Comment: Below I outline the general steps of what I did:

Comment: 1 - Create a separate custom object called Timer.

Comment: 2 - In the new object, create new fields: 'Start time' and 'End Time' (Both Datetime fields)

Comment: 3 - Create a master-detail relationship: Account (Master) to Timer (detail)

Comment: 4 - Create formula field in Timer object which will calculate the difference between 'Start time' and 'End time'. This will create a result in decimals (ie, one and half days = 1.5)

Comment: 5 - (assuming knowledge of creating custom button and URL hacking here) Create a button on the Account side, which opens URL which points to a new Timer record. You will need to hard code within the URL so that on the new record creation page, start time is {!NOW}

Comment: 6 - Create a button on the Timer record detail side, which opens URL which points to the current Timer record. You will need to hard code within the URL so that on the record edit page, End time is {!NOW}

Comment: 7 - Create an indicator (eg, coloured block) so that user knows that a timer is ongoing (when 'start time' is not blank and 'end time' is blank)

Comment: 8 - Create a rollup field on Account side which will roll up the formula field we create before (for calculating the difference between the Start time and End time), in order to get the total elapsed time

Comment: Yes, I know this solution may not look as elegant as actually using Apex or Visualforce, but the users were over the moon at the moment, and as I said I am not a programmer by training.

If anyone have other ideas, that would be greatly appreciated