# Inserting records in a custom object after fetching the details entered in a pop up

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am very new to Salesforce. I am stuck at a point where I have to add/insert records in one or more custom objects.

The details (such as name, address, phone) to be inserted in the custom object are entered by the user in a pop-up form. Once the required information is entered by the user and the'SAVE' button is clicked the data should get stored in a custom object in a single record.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: welcome to sfse juhi, could you share the code you've already written ? Have you already looked into "DML methods/documentation ?"

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Are you hitting an error of some kind?  Where are you stuck?  If you are just giving the forum a list of requirements looking for code, this question will likely go unanswered.  If you have attempted this and have hit a wall or barrier of some sort, please let us know where you are stuck, share your code so far and we would be glad to help.

Comment: hey guys.. thanks a lot.. i found out my mistake. the problem is resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment on the system, as I do not have enough reputation yet, but I hope the system admins will allow me to put my answer/comment here.

You mentioned popup form, is that a requirement? If you need a popup form, then it may be a visualforce wizard/form which you may need to create using Apex, or another way is to create custom buttons and use some URL hacking to create new records.

Below is a link to something I did, using a new button to create new records on custom objects - see if that might give you some ideas :
[Creating a stopwatch in salesforce which calculates total time elapsed without using apex or visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41604/creating-a-stopwatch-in-salesforce-which-calculates-total-time-elapsed-without-u)

When you create a new button, Salesforce will ask you how the page will  act when you click on the button. There will be an option for popup. In my example, I chose to keep it on the same page.

If a popup form is not a requirement, then once you create a new custom object, make it available to view for the users by create a tab for it. Once a tab is created, users could click on it, and then there will be a button for new record there. However, at this point, you must be wary of permissions - roles and profiles and any custom Public Groups or permission sets which might restrict users from viewing the object and the records.

I know this is a very generalised answer, but hopefully that is a start.